# Java Apache Poi Write Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I working in an application in Java to write to an excel. I am using apache poi libraries. I have a requirement to create pivot table. I am able to create pivot table and sum the columns using below code.

```
CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(0, 0);
CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(10, 3);
AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
CellReference pos = new CellReference(0, 0);
XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("PivotSheet");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(aref,pos,dataSheet)
pivotOrgWiseSheet.setDisplayGridlines(true);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2, "Sum of column3");
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3, "Sum of column4");
```

But the above code generate excel like 
[image]

But I am not sure why the keyword "values" comes in 2nd column header and also is it possible to change the value "Row Label" to custom text like "Category"

I want it something like below.

[image]

I am not sure how to remove the keyword "Values", but I guess to change the header to custom string, we have to get the value and set it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Excel` there is a setting `Field Headers` on the `Analyze` or `Options` tab, in the `Show` group. This switches between showing and hiding field headers.

See [Change the layout of columns, rows, and subtotals](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc273370207).

The corresponding setting in `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotTableDefinition` is `setShowHeaders`.

So

```
...
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setShowHeaders(false);
...
```

should hiding field headers in your pivot table.

But your picture of the wanted result looks more as if the data headers are visible but the `RowHeaderCaption` was changed and first row containing the `DataCaption` is hidden. That would be:

```
...
//pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setShowHeaders(false);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("Category");
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setDataCaption("Changed Data Caption");
CellUtil.getRow(pos.getRow(), pivotSheet).setZeroHeight(true);
...
```